# Accordion like menu - sub-menu not hiding while click on another link - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu made with ul an li, and I am trying to hide other sub-menus when a click event is triggered on a anchor.
The HTML menu looks like this

```
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">link 1</a>
            <ul class="subnavi">
                <li><a href="#">sublink 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sublink 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">link 2</a>
            <ul class="subnavi">
                <li><a href="#">sublink 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sublink 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">link 3</a>
            <ul class="subnavi">
                <li><a href="#">sublink 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sublink 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">link 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

the CSS code looks like this

```
#navigation li ul{ display: none;}
```

an the Jquery part looks like this

```
    $('#navigation > li:has(ul) > a').on("click",function(ev) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle().end().siblings().find('ul').hide();
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the followig jQuery code:

```
   $('#navigation > li:has(ul) > a').on("click",function(ev) {
       $('#navigation .subnavi').hide(); //This hides all the sub menus
       $(this).siblings('ul').toggle().end().siblings().find('ul').hide();
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/82jJv/

Answer (score 1):

At first, hide all submenus:

```
$('.subnavi').hide();
```

and then make visible current actual submenu